# Display webcam feed in Qt window

Tags: python, pyqt, webcam

I'm a bit stuck here. I would like to display a webcam live feed in a PyQt5 window.
When i push the button the feed has to start, button turns green and text changes to "Stop camera" , on the next click the feed has to stop and the button has to revert to its original status and the feed is replaced with an image.
At the moment i only get a still image.

As soon as i get this working i would like to add some threading

Here is the code (updated):

```
import os
import threading
import timeit

import cv2
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QThread, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi


class Worker1(QThread):
    ImageUpdate = pyqtSignal(QImage)

    def run(self):

        self.ThreadActive = True
        self.Capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

        while self.ThreadActive:
            ret, frame = self.Capture.read()
            if ret:
                Image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                FlippedImage = cv2.flip(Image, 1)
                ConvertToQtFormat = QImage(FlippedImage.data, FlippedImage.shape[1], FlippedImage.shape[0], QImage.Format_RGB888)
                Pic = ConvertToQtFormat.scaled(640, 480, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
                self.ImageUpdate.emit(Pic)

        self.Capture.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    def stop(self):
        self.ThreadActive = False
        self.terminate()

class FaceIdWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(FaceIdWindow, self).__init__()

        self.ui = loadUi("uidesign/facereco/FaceId.ui", self)
        self.ui.cmdChoosePicture.clicked.connect(self.ChoosePicture)
        self.ui.cmdStartCamera.clicked.connect(self.StartCamera)
        self.ui.cmdTrainFace.clicked.connect(self.TrainFace)
        self.ui.cmdProcess.clicked.connect(self.Process)
        self.status_camera = "STOPPED"


    def StartCamera(self):
        start = timeit.default_timer()
        start = timeit.default_timer()
        print("Start StartCamera\n")
        print(self.status_camera)

        if  self.status_camera == "STOPPED":
            self.status_camera = "STARTED"
            self.ui.cmdStartCamera.setStyleSheet("background-color: green")
            self.ui.cmdStartCamera.setText("Stop camera")
            self.Worker1 = Worker1()
            self.Worker1.start()
            self.Worker1.ImageUpdate.connect(self.ImageUpdateSlot)

        else:
            self.status_camera = "STOPPED"
            self.Worker1.stop()
            image_path = str(os.getcwd())
            image_path = image_path + "/assets/clipart/clipartfaceid2.png"
            self.lblPicture.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(image_path))
            self.ui.cmdStartCamera.setStyleSheet("background-color: ")
            self.ui.cmdStartCamera.setText("Start camera")


        print("Stop StartCamera\n")
        end = timeit.default_timer()
        print("Process Time: ", (end - start))

    def ImageUpdateSlot(self, Image):
        self.lblPicture.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(Image))
```

Any suggestions ?

Cheers , John

Comment: Found some info online , the updated code is working ok but when i click the button the second time the application closes , no info from the debugger. Don't know if this important but the window is started from another window.

Comment: I updated (again) , this is running stable , i can shutdown and start the webcam feed  , nothing crashes ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Seems i wasn't starting and stopping my thread in the right place.Code is updated , but if anyone has any improvements don't hesitate! Cheers John

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).